# If a variable does not exist in a batch

Tags: batch-file

I am stuck.  I have a section of a script that looks for a filenumber, and if it exists, I want it to go to the next command of the script.  If it does not exist, I want it to go back to the spot where the user enters the filenumber again.  Basically, if they enter a file number that does not exist, I want them to re-enter the filenumber.  If it does exist, I wnat them to proceed.  What I am getting is a loop and I can't figure out where I can get out of it.  Here is the code I have

```
    :FileNum
cls
set /P "FileNumber=Please enter File Number: "
if defined FileNumber for /R "\bpclient\A001\M0093" %%I in ("*%FileNumber%*.xml") do copy /Y "%%I" "\IlnevalExtractionTool\Data\"

IF NOT EXIST "%FileNumber%" (
   echo File Number %FileNumber% Does Not Exist
   echo Try again
   pause
   goto :FileNum 
)
IF EXIST "%FileNumber%" (
goto: result   
) 
@echo off

:result
cls
@echo off
copy Data\*.xml Results.txt
```

If I enter a filenumber that exists, it copies them to the data folder, but then gives me the echo text I have for "File Number XXXX Does not exist. try again" and takes me back to the Please Enter File Number prompt.  How can I get it to go to the result section of the script if the variable exists, but loop back if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking it if the `number` you typed exists, which I suppose never will, instead you want to test if the actual file exists. So to directly fix the issue.

```
:FileNum
cls
set /P "FileNumber=Please enter File Number: "
if defined FileNumber for /R "\bpclient\A001\M0093" %%I in ("*%FileNumber%*.xml") do (
    copy /Y "%%I" "\IlnevalExtractionTool\Data\"
    set "fname=%%~I"
)

IF NOT EXIST "%fname%" (
   echo File Number %FileNumber% Does Not Exist
   echo Try again
   pause
   goto :FileNum 
)
IF EXIST "%fname%" (
goto: result   
) 
@echo off

:result
cls
@echo off
copy Data\*.xml Results.txt
```

But I would instead do:

```
@echo off
:FileNum
set fname=
set /P "FileNumber=Please enter File Number: "
if defined FileNumber for /R "\bpclient\A001\M0093" %%I in ("*%FileNumber%*.xml") do (
    copy /Y "%%I" "\IlnevalExtractionTool\Data\"
    set "fname=%%~I"
)
if defined fname (
    copy "data\*.xml" Results.txt
) else (
    echo File not found Please try again.
    goto :fileNum
)
```